# Changing ViewModel Object does not reflect the changes to the View

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have implemented a User Control in which I have bound the `DataContext` to itself like this...

```
this.DataContext = this;
```

There is a Combo box on top of the User Control. On it's selection change event. I am updating a property of the `UserControl` which should cause the entire View to be regenerated including some tabs in a `TabControl` and the `TextBoxes`.

On the selection change event I am updating the property like this...

```
this.CurrentViewModel = viewModel;
```

Here is some of the sample xaml from the view.

```
<TextBox 
    x:Name="txtPageSetupAlias" 
    Width="500" 
    Padding="2,5,0,0" 
    Text="{Binding Path=CurrentViewModel.ValidPageSetupAlias, Mode=TwoWay}" 
    Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=txtAlias}" DockPanel.Dock="Left" 
    />

<TabControl 
    x:Name="tcOrientation" 
    Grid.Row="1" 
    BorderBrush="Transparent" 
    BorderThickness="0"
    Margin="0,0,0,0" 
    TabStripPlacement="Top" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding Path=CurrentViewModel.Orientations}">
```

and inside the TabControl...

```
<TabControl.ContentTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Grid>
            <StackPanel 
                Orientation="Horizontal" 
                Margin="0,0,0,5">
                <TextBlock 
                    Text="Page Width:" 
                    Style="{StaticResource tbDataLabel}" 
                    Margin="0,0,34,0"
                    />
                <Border 
                    Width="98" 
                    CornerRadius="5" 
                    BorderBrush="#CCCCCC" 
                    Background="White" 
                    BorderThickness="1" 
                    Margin="7,0,0,0" 
                    >
                    <xctk:DecimalUpDown 
                        x:Name="pageDimWidth" 
                        Value="{Binding Path=PageWidth, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, NotifyOnValidationError=True}" 
                        Validation.Error="page_Error" Increment="0.10"  
                        ParsingNumberStyle="Float" 
                        Style="{StaticResource dudValues}"
                        d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance dtOs:PageSizeOrientationViewModel}" 
                        />
```

**UPDATE 1:**
Here is the `CurrentViewModel` property

```
private PageSetupEditorViewModel _currentViewModel;
public PageSetupEditorViewModel CurrentViewModel
{
    get { return _currentViewModel; }
    set
    {
        _currentViewModel = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(CurrentViewModel));
    }
}

public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

public void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
{
    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

Can anybody tell me what I am missing here...

**UPDATE 2:**
Sharing the combo selection change event:

```
private void cmbPageSetupTemplate_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    _errors = 0;
    var validPageSetup = cmbPageSetupTemplate.SelectedItem as PageSetupEditorViewModel;
    CurrentViewModel = viewModel;
    this.DataContext = this;
}
```

Comment: Have you implemented `INotifyPropertyChanged` for `CurrentViewModel`?

Comment: Can you show us your ViewModel?

Comment: I have implemented the `INotifyPropertyChanged` for `CurrentViewModel`, but now my view has gone blank after updation

Comment: 1) "There is a Combo box on top of the User Control": What does "on top of" mean? Is it inside your UserControl or outside? 2) "I am updating a property of the UserControl which should cause the entire View to be regenerated": Can you share all of that code? The event handler and the property. Unseen code that "should" do something very often turns out that it actually shouldn't.

Comment: @EdPlunkett I have updated the question above. The combo is in the same User Control :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So apparently, I had to do two things to make it work.

Since I was binding the User Control to itself like this...

```
this.DataContext = this;
```

I had to implement `INotifyPropertyChange` on the User Control class itself and implement the `PropertyChanged` call on the `CurrentViewModel` property, like this:

```
private PageSetupEditorViewModel _currentViewModel;
public PageSetupEditorViewModel CurrentViewModel
{
    get { return _currentViewModel; }
    set
    {
        _currentViewModel = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(CurrentViewModel));
    }
}

public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

public void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
{
    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

But that did not entirely updated the view as I was using a collection to generate tabs in the `TabControl`.

I had to refresh the view for `TabComtrol.Items` using this on the selection of `ComboBox`'s selection change event, like this:

```
tcOrientation.Items.Refresh();
```

This solved the problem for me :)